# Export single .d.ts from several typescript files + entrypoint

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I've several .ts files + 1 entrypoint like so:

- classA.ts
- classB.ts
- entrypoint.ts

`entrypoint.ts` contains something similar to:

```
export * from './classA';
export * from './classB';
```

I'd like to have a single .d.ts describing everything entrypoint exports so that both `ClassA` and `ClassB` definition files are included.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot auto-generate a single `d.ts` file. What works fine is the following (assuming you are building a library / reusable module):

1. have the compiler auto-generate declarations for your classes by specifying  `"declaration": true` in `tsconfig.json`
2. the compiler will also generate an `entrypoint.d.ts` file (that re-exports the `d.ts`of classA and classB)
3. Point the `typings` entry of your `package.json` to `entrypoint.d.ts` e.g. `"typings": "./dist/entrypoint.d.ts"`

Assuming your library is called `library`, you can now install it in the `node_modules` of a project and use it with a standard import:

```
import {classA, classB} from 'library'
```

will import the generated `d.ts.` for those classes.

Comment: Step 2 did not happen for me. The index.d.ts file (which exports all the other *.ts files in the project simply had the line "export {};"

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who finds this post. You can try **[npm-dts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-dts)** utility. This should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

This one worked for me and it was pretty straight forward: https://github.com/TypeStrong/dts-bundle

I tried these without luck:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/dts-gen
- https://github.com/SitePen/dts-generator